# android sqlite query

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a table that is called `books` and 
it has fields:  `title, author, isbn, year`

So when i want to insert a title, i search first for the isbn number. If i find a match, I  don't insert the book, i just update the row.

My question is how can i query the isbn from the table and check if there is a match or not?

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do:

```
db.query("books", null, "isbn = ?", new String[] {isbn}, null, null, null);
```

where `db` is an instance of `SQLiteDatabase` and `isbn` is the book you want to search for.  If you get any rows in the result, then you know the book already exists and you should update it.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the ISBN a key, and then use [replace()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.InsertHelper.html#replace%28android.content.ContentValues%29). That would only add a new row if the ISBN didn't exist, otherwise it would replace that row with the new data.